# use wavelet transform to extract frequencies from given signal

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, wavelet

let us suppose that we have following signal  values,which consists  by deterministic  components and random noise(white noise)

```
56.69
75.24
13.77
8.56
-12.88
-65.34
-45.33
-48.78
-22.23
54.12
83.77
11.84
2.31
39.59
-32.09
-88.86
5.45
50.24
-37.39
-35.69
38.62
7.06
-30.01
22.36
60.71
30.96
5.90
-38.91
-58.15
-40.87
-13.18
-14.77
35.36
103.24
39.04
-50.76
6.98
1.23
-87.46
-60.86
65.08
23.93
-28.36
2.42
31.67
-5.22
4.02
37.50
12.36
5.37
-18.83
-68.70
-38.11
35.47
7.47
11.64
103.89
88.26
-62.41
-62.44
10.09
-33.92
-72.48
17.83
74.35
7.56
-5.35
22.56
-2.11
-2.82
2.59
-21.33
-0.52
-4.11
-50.68
-66.68
28.14
62.10
6.73
32.39
93.62
-18.56
-112.15
-38.18
3.33
-44.78
13.79
76.52
39.92
9.55
-7.09
-28.72
-1.59
19.01
-26.25
-22.61
32.54
0.06
-80.17
-2.02
103.68
31.50
-9.29
44.79
6.10
-93.30
-87.67
2.06
5.53
20.94
67.28
48.24
16.43
4.28
-49.05
-43.92
14.48
2.02
-56.29
16.29
54.09
-42.38
-33.91
67.16
64.26
-34.38
1.31
17.57
-69.49
-86.43
-14.43
20.61
38.08
66.31
38.91
9.62
-4.38
-45.47
-91.23
-9.17
52.92
-21.17
-31.51
69.74
22.55
-62.65
22.34
72.59
-6.34
-49.96
0.06
-38.30
-55.57
-22.15
28.14
61.12
81.82
37.94
-32.41
-14.05
-16.05
-90.12
-46.52
75.39
50.48
-36.08
21.54
64.57
-32.83
-47.71
47.82
35.80
-31.32
-37.71
-30.45
-36.51
6.90
30.17
25.81
69.67
50.19
-55.42
-76.26
-11.97
-47.71
-80.69
52.76
91.17
-5.08
-12.75
49.10
5.44
-46.98
-0.40
22.20
-12.89
-17.56
-24.62
-18.95
22.94
53.27
8.67
35.09
67.76
-27.38
-111.75
-37.70
14.80
-56.16
2.87
105.52
59.46
-42.36
-7.17
12.65
-32.87
-38.61
-0.33
1.07
0.12
6.79
-41.04
3.19
76.28
18.78
-26.27
47.46
16.52
-116.17
-82.44
25.21
8.68
2.55
70.61
86.29
-10.63
-44.12
-19.48
-34.54
-31.95
8.52
-10.48
11.89
40.45
-10.66
-34.27
63.24
42.83
-32.87
-18.44
37.47
-64.48
-101.98
7.93
59.48
22.63
43.46
74.91
2.31
-49.18
-56.15
-55.96
-11.68
37.66
3.36
13.40
45.50
14.21
-57.98
6.29
74.98
-7.25
-70.83
12.29
7.90
-76.29
-24.42
69.80
60.11
28.97
39.65
-11.23
-59.30
-60.80
-63.71
-16.72
66.48
59.98
-17.27
36.01
55.04
-38.70
-59.95
48.63
```

i know that sampling frequency=100;i am interested what is a  basic steps  using wavelet to extract  frequencies and phases?i know that there is function of  cwt for compute continuous wavelet transform and from coefficients it tries to determine  frequencies,now if i know  sampling frequency and dont know  frequency components but suppose that it must be less then  sampling frequency/2 or fs/2,because of Nyquist criteria to held,how can i take  scales?i have tried following example

```
>> B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
>> scales=1:100;
>> coeff=cwt(B,1:100,'db2','plot');
```

and got following picture

[image]

now how can i determine  which frequency and phases are in signal?or which wavelet basis should i choose?please help me in this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer inside the framework you set:

In the CWT domain the frequencies will stay the same, the wavelet will behave just like any other filter. It will only filter out frequencies, not change them. You can see banded regions in the image where the peaks are. Since you picked a wavelet that does not have a very steep frequency response, "beating" is visible and appears to be about as strong as the signal itself.

If you choose a wavelet with better frequency resolution (a longer one), the signals will stand out better.

If you try to do a DWT, you will get aliases, and the signals are not far enough apart to separate them completely.

Comment: just one concrete example if you can show  ?because i am new  and dont know well how to extract frequencies

Comment: Morlet/Gabor-Wavelets are basically windowed oscillations. If you make the window larger, you will gain frequency resolution and lose spatial resolution.

Comment: yes but please show how to to in matlab it?please show me

Comment: Maybe you try the Y of "X=linspace(-5,5,40);Y=sin(10*X).*exp(-X.^2)" instead of "db2"

Answer (score 1):

A simple (hanning-windowed) FFT reveals four peaks that stand out far beyond the noise. This appears to be what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: but how it could be  frequencies,when sampling frequency is 100?

Comment: i can  find frequencies using periodogram  methods( these are not correct frequencies),what i want  is using wavelet to  find  frequencies,just using  wavelets

Comment: FFT bin 25 would stand for frequency 25/294*100 Hz ~= 8.5 Hz.

Comment: ok but what about  wavelet?

Comment: Why do you want to use wavelet decomposition? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to study  extraction of  frequencies and phases from wavelet scales

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Crosswavelet and Wavelet Coherence package linked below:

http://noc.ac.uk/using-science/crosswavelet-wavelet-coherence

A Morlet mother wavelet should serve you well if you're looking for periodic behavior.